# Does the deconv operation really require knowing the output shape?

Tags: tensorflow, deconvolution

The documentation for the [deconv operation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.nn.conv2d_transpose.md) says that we need to provide the output_shape. Is it possible to not provide the first element of the shape tensor? When i try to provide a None in the shape tensor (also note that the shape of value has a None as first element), I get an error which goes something like:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 276, in conv2d_transposeoutput_shape_ = ops.convert_to_tensor(output_shape, name="output_shape")

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 621, in convert_to_tensor ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 180, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 163, in constant
tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 421, in make_tensor_proto
tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 45, in as_bytes
(bytes_or_text,))

 TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None
```

Comment: You need to provide a shape. You can provide a partially specified shape if you make a TensorShape yourself.

Comment: OP, could you provide the actual code you're running that produces this answer to help clarify?  Thanks!